# Update a row(entity) in a table only if a change detected(automatically)

Tags: sql-update, entity, cakephp-3.0, detect

Sorry for my bad english :(

I'm using the **CAKEPHP 3 framework** and i want to **update a row**(entity) in a table only if **a change detected**(automatically).

Eg.:

```
$id = 1;
// debug($this->request->data)
$this->request->data = ['id' => 1, 'name' => "My Name", 'content' => "My Content"];
// Inside the ArticlesController
$article = $this->Articles->get($id);
// debug($article)
object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {
    'id' => (int) 1,
    'name' => "My Name",
    'content' => "My Content",
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Articles'
}
```

There is **no difference** between **the request data** and **the original data** so i have to **reject the update query** and **return a warning** to the user "**No changes detected !**"

What i have to do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each entity has a field 'dirty' which shows if the entity has been updated.

You could use something like :

```
if($article->dirty()) {
    // send a flash message
}
```

Check the book here : http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#checking-if-an-entity-has-been-modified

Comment: no the dirty method doesn't detect if the value of a specific key has been changed :(
if you just add  ```$article->name = "My Name"``` after the ```$this->Articles->get($id);``` you will get ```'[dirty]' => ['name' => true]```

Comment: Isn't it what you wanted ? You will be able to check if `patchEntity` updated your entity in `ArticlesController`.

Comment: yes ```patchEntity``` will guess the difference between **the orignal data** and **the request data** :)

Comment: So doesn't it answer your question ? Or did I misunderstood something ?